# Can't get this canvas html5 game to work in my chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Here's the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/z2pqr9620m

It obviously works in that website's environment, but for some reasons my browser won't really display it properly.

Any help is appreciated! Have a good day.

Comment: Hit `FILE` menu item, and `export to zip`. You get all the code, host it somewhere and check it out.

Comment: are you using parcel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use modules in javascript instead of .js files you have to rename them to .mjs.
More information here => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

And you can find some exemples here => https://github.com/mdn/js-examples/tree/master/modules